# What is the pivot in MVVM pattern?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, model-view-controller, mvvm

When it comes to the MVC pattern, I have always thought of the controller as the pivot. That is, it is the one that receives all actions that the user wishes to perform and it then decides which model and view to use to complete the user requested action. (My experience with MVC is through Asp.net and so I am thinking of how routes are used to pick the correct controller which then loads the model and selects and creates the appropriate view).

Is there a pivot in the MVVM pattern? Is the view the pivot in that the user interacts with the pivot which then can result in different model being loaded and presented to the user using the appropriate VM?

Also, where does the logic that normally sits in the controller in MVC sit in the MVVM pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVVM is more distributed than MVC. Views and view models are typically bound at design time, which means that the VM does not perform the same function as an MVC controller. It is more of a pure coordinator than a controller--a good view model generally has relatively little decision logic.

The whole idea behind MVVM is to isolate the graphical elements of a view from its programmatic elements. It similarities to MVC are really only superficial. In MVC, a controller acts as an executive, the real intelligence behind an application. In MVVM, the VM acts only as a programmatic abstraction of a view, and the intelligence is distributed throughout the application.

MVVM components act in a collaborative, distributed manner, which tends to eliminate the monolithic concentration that permeates some MVC apps. It takes a bit of getting used to but it works very well. Think of an MVVM app as a mechanical swiss watch--what is the pivot point of a watch? There really isn't one. A watch is a collection of autonomous components that work together to perform a task. There really isn't a 'pivot point' than masterminds the operation.

Comment: David I like your answer. But when the user clicks on a button on a certain view, where is the logic that decides what must be done next (load another view, persist the data in the current view or maybe both). Is this logic a part of the view or the view-model?

Comment: The view model generally acts as a coordinator. It will decide who fulfills the request made by the button click. But it generally doesn't take that action itself--it is generally delegated to a Command or Service object. That keeps the view model uncluttered and focused on its responsibility of directing traffic.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an equivalent pivot in MVVM.  However I suppose the view could choose its VM.  For testing purposes, you can use the VM without a view.  The control logic is in the ViewModel.

I like to think of MVVM as  M <-> VM  <-> V

A good description of the VM is from Fowler who calls it [Presentation Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think in MVVM it would be the view.  The view responds to user actions, and then decides how to respond.  It will call one method on the VM or another based on the users action.  The VM then carries out the action.

I think you can further split MVVM into two flavors as well; one with a rich model, vs. one with an anemic model.  [This link](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/faq/Mvvm.ashx) about the Csla framework has some discussions on what a "rich" model provides vs. anemic.

Answer (score 0):

In MVVM, your view just displays your data.  Just like what the view does in MVC. So that leaves your model doing all the work.

If you put a button on an asp.net page, an you press it, that's just like putting a button on a silverlight page.  The model of that view when using MVVM, will handle all the action it needs to do on itself to manipulate the data.  The view will respond (via binding) accordingly.  In MVC the controler would decide what action to proform on the model.

So the M & C in the MVC "View Model", is merged into one M in the MV "View Model".